# first time out of many with ssh "permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: ssh, key

Forgive me, I know this has been asked so many times, and I read most of the answers. The difference between this question and other questions is that, in my case I did this procedure so many times. But this time is the first time in my life this is not working and I can't debug this.

I created a new ssh key in the client (windows 10), and added it to the authorized keys in the server (Ubuntu 20.04) through another authorized client (Ubuntu 20.04), restarted ssh, but I can't connect: it throws me the classic error `"permission denied (public key)"`
As I stated in the beginning, I did this so many times without any problem at all.

I don't know what I should do to fix it, everything looks ok..

**UPDATE**
I forgot to mention one important thing, using:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/private_key username@host
```

I can connect to the server without any problem.
I don't know why the simple ssh command is not working. I just have one key set up in the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the ssh-agent in the background.

`$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

then

Add your SSH private key to the ssh-agent.

`$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/private_key`

Comment: thanks, apparently this solved the problem

Comment: Happy to help. Suffered with this problem quite frequently and each time it works.